# Torch Tensor flatten, pad and unflatten again

Tags: pytorch, padding, tensor

I have a torch.tensor with dimensions (2, 3):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I want to create tensor with dimensions (2, 5) like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 0 0 0 0
```

How do I can do this effectively?
Also for backward transform.

Comment: What do you mean by effectively?

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
import torch
from torch.nn.functional import pad

a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6]])

desired_shape = torch.tensor([2, 5])

padded = pad(a.flatten(), (0, torch.prod(desired_shape) - a.numel()))

reshaped = padded.view(*desired_shape)
```

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6]])

b = torch.zeros(10, dtype=a.dtype)
b[0:a.numel()] = a.flatten()
b = b.reshape((2, 5))
```